# Button Set/Button Bar in Dojo

Tags: dojo, buttonbar

I need to present my users with a choice of two options.

I want these to be nice big buttons to click, as opposed to a [RadioButton](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/form/RadioButton.html), where the label is usually not a clickable element but just a traditional small circle to click.

e.g.

[image]

As the user clicks each one, a function is called with a different variable, so that some other magic can happen elsewhere in my application.

I saw [how this can be done in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272663/jquery-ui-object-button-bar-that-works-like-radio-buttons), so that is going to be my backup plan.

Seeing as im trying to learn Dojo and 90% of the app is currently built on Dojo (1.7), I was hoping there would be a similar component to this within Dojo.

I assume I could place two separate [Dojo buttons](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/form/Button.html) alongside each other, and have a global variable catch which one has currently been last clicked, and when it has, ensure the other button becomes disabled, but this does not sound that elegant.

**What is the best way to achieve a choice of two buttons, where when one is clicked, the other button becomes disabled, and a function is fired with a particular value?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use something like this (note that i havent run the code)

```
<button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ToggleButton" id='toggle1' data-dojo-props="iconClass:'dijitCheckBoxIcon', checked: true">
<button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ToggleButton" id='toggle2' data-dojo-props="iconClass:'dijitCheckBoxIcon', checked: false">​
```

and this javascript:

```
​dojo.require('dojo.parser');
dojo.require('dojo.form.ToggleButton');

dojo.ready(function(){
    dojo.parser.parse();
    dojo.connect(dijit.byId('toggle1'),'onChange',function(){
        dijit.byId('toggle2').set('checked',false);
        //what you want to do
    });
    dojo.connect(dijit.byId('toggle1'),'onChange',function(){
        dijit.byId('toggle2').set('checked',false);
        //what you want to do
    });
```

});​

note that I havent checked the code, so it may need some modifications